# Flow-root alternative with Hidden Overflow child

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, overflow

I have a div that sits between two floated elements and takes up the remaining space by setting `overflow:hidden` on `.middle-select`. The issue is, inside of that div I have elements that need to be overflowed, so I set `.positionRelative` to `position:relative`.

```
<div class="noLink panel panel-default">
    <label class="floated-label">label</label>

    <div class="floated-stuff">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
    </div>

    <div class="positionRelative">
        <div class="middle-select">
<!-- overflowing stuff-->
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The issue is that the `positionRelative` element takes up the entire width of the `panel`, rather than only taking up only the width of `middle-select`. Using `display:flow-root` on `positionRelative` fixes that issue, but is there a more browser-compatible solution? [See example here](https://www.bootply.com/kW0Jsugssq)